# Injecting pre-release versions into CSPROJ NuPkg generation

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

I'm using the new CSPROJ schema introduced in Visual Studio 2017.
Additionally, I use this to create a NuPkg for my assembly.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  <PackageId>MyComponent</PackageId>
  <Version>2.1.0</Version>
 .
 .
 .
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm using VSTS to build my solution and I'd like to use the build to control the package quality, by adding a pre-release designation to the  tag. Something like this:

```
  <Version>2.1.0$(VERSIONSUFFIX)</Version>
```

To yield package names such as:

- MyComponent.2.1.0-alpha-12345.nupkg
- MyComponent.2.1.0-beta-67890.nupkg
- MyComponent.2.1.0.nupkg

This works ok, but I found a nasty side effect - if I edit the version number interactively in Visual Studio it strips the `$(VERSIONSUFFIX)` placeholder. The only way I can update the version number is to edit the CSPROJ directly.

Is there a better way of allowing the build to control the NuPkg generation?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 1):

The editor will always change `Version` and remove all customisations.

The suggested way of the new SDK is to set `VersionPrefix` in the build and `VersionSuffix` - if set - will be appended to it.

So you'd have

```
<VersionPrefix>1.2.3</VersionPrefix>
```

and could build using `-p:VersionSuffix=beta-123` to produce a `1.2.3-beta-123.nupkg` file.
But editing in VS properties becomes impossible in any way.

Comment: Didn't know about the <VersionPrefix> and <VersionSuffix>, thanks for the info! That said, it looks like that still doesn't solve my problem with the editor. If I set <VersionPrefix> in the CSPROJ and remove <Version>, I see the "version" in the package properties editor, but if I update it there it writes a new <Version> tag in the CSPROJ (not updating <VersionPrefix>) and then the build seems to now ignore the <VersionPrefix> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use build variables to specify the package version and prefix version in NuGet pack task as you need.

If you  want to use assembly version for the package version and change the prefix version as you want, you can use below steps:

#### 1.   Get assembly version

You can add the task [Assembly Info Reader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kherzog.AssemblyInfoReader), then you can get the assembly version by the variable `$(ASSEMBLYINFO.ASSEMBLYVERSION)`.

#### 2.   Define package version and prefix version as you need

You can define a variable in your build definition to specify the prefix version only. Such as the variable `ver` with the prefix part `beta-1.1`.

[image]

Add a PowerShell task to combine `$(ASSEMBLYINFO.ASSEMBLYVERSION)` and the prefix version together for packing nuget package. The PowerShell script can be:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ver]$(ASSEMBLYINFO.ASSEMBLYVERSION)-$(ver)"
```

So the variable `$(ver)` contains the version with prefix version.

#### 3.   Specify the defined version with prefix for the package to be pack

In NuGet pack task, select Use an environment variable for Automatic package versioning option and specify `ver` as the Environment variable.

[image]

Then the packed package will as the format `MyComponent.2.1.0-beta-1.1.nupkg` etc.